# JFace TableViewer header foreground color only switches on mouseover

Tags: java, swt, jface, rcp

I have a part that contains a TableViewer. I want to color the header label differntly. This is how I currently do it.

```
public class UsagePart {

    private TableViewer viewer;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createControls(final Composite parent) {
        final TableColumnLayout tableColumnLayout = new TableColumnLayout();
        parent.setLayout(tableColumnLayout);

        viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);

        final Table table = viewer.getTable();
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);
        table.setHeaderForeground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_LINK_FOREGROUND));

        final TableViewerColumn nameColumn = createTableViewerColumn("Name");

        tableColumnLayout.setColumnData(nameColumn.getColumn(), new ColumnWeightData(1, 100, true));
    }

    private TableViewerColumn createTableViewerColumn(final String title) {
        final TableViewerColumn viewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
        final TableColumn column = viewerColumn.getColumn();
        column.setText(title);
        column.setResizable(true);
        column.setMoveable(true);
        return viewerColumn;
    }   
}
```

But doing it like this, the color of the header only changes when I hover over it. Additionally the color is resetted each time I switch Perspectives/Views.

I found out that this is caused by the TableColumnLayout. Without it the color is always applied, but my columns do not fill the space of the View. I don't know why the TableColumnLayout causes this behavior.
How do I achieve both?

Comment: On macOS, this looks good. Which OS/Window system do you use?

Comment: I use Windows 10

Comment: This looks like a bug and you may want to file a bug report here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform

Comment: Ok, that is what I suspected, thanks for confirming that.

Comment: Could you post a link to the bug report here, for reference?

Comment: Reported the bug here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533311

Comment: To increase the likelihood that your bug gets addressed, I would put some more effort to precisely describe the problem, ideally with a standalone snippet for others to easily reproduce.